# Can't upgrade to latest SVN Format

Tags: svn, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I am having a hard time upgrading to the latest version of SVN on my Mac. I downloaded homebrew and that helped me get from 1.7 to 1.8.10, however now when I try to commit I get the following message:

```
    The working copy at '/Users/rmyers/Desktop/XcodeRepo/AppName'
    is too old (format 29) to work with client version '1.8.10 (r1615264)' 
(expects format 31). You need to upgrade the working copy first.
```

I've tried running a "svn upgrade" command as well as trying to upgrade it through brew again, but it just tells me its up to date. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you specifically try `svn upgrade /Users/rmyers/Desktop/XcodeRepo/AppName` as your command? You need to upgrade your WORKING COPY not your version of SVN, so homebrew shouldn't come into play for the solution.

Comment: `svn upgrade` without parameter will give you needed result only if current dir is old WC. Otherwise - re-read @Ben comment

Comment: Thanks @Ben. It was the working copy. Put your solution as an answer and I'll select it if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`svn upgrade` needs to either be ran from within each working copy, or you need to pass it the path to each working copy. For example, `svn upgrade /Users/rmyers/Desktop/XcodeRepo/AppName`